# Copy a Google Drive folder recursively with Python - 403 error

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

I try to copy a Google Drive folder (files & subfolders) with the following Python script but I get a 403 error. The setup of the credentials should be fine because when exchanging the copy function with another function to list all files, it works.

```py
import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json'
CREDENTIALS_PATH = 'credentials.json'

def get_credentials():
    # Gets user credentials or prompts for authorization if needed.
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(TOKEN_PATH, SCOPES) if os.path.exists(TOKEN_PATH) else None

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CREDENTIALS_PATH, SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

        # Save the credentials for future runs
        with open(TOKEN_PATH, 'w') as token_file:
            token_file.write(creds.to_json())

    return creds

def copy_file(drive_service, source_file_id, destination_folder_id):
    # Create a copy request
    copy_request = {
        'name': None,  # Keep the same name as the original file
        'parents': [destination_folder_id],
    }

    try:
        # Copy the file
        copied_file = drive_service.files().copy(
            fileId=source_file_id, body=copy_request
        ).execute()

        print(f'File copied with ID: {copied_file["id"]}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'An error occurred while copying file: {str(e)}')

def copy_folder_recursive(drive_service, source_folder_id, destination_folder_id):
    # Copy the current folder
    copy_file(drive_service, source_folder_id, destination_folder_id)

    # List all files and subfolders in the current folder
    results = drive_service.files().list(
        q=f"'{source_folder_id}' in parents",
        fields="files(id, name, mimeType)").execute()

    # Recursively copy subfolders and their contents
    for item in results.get('files', []):
        if item['mimeType'] == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder':
            copy_folder_recursive(
                drive_service, item['id'], copied_folder['id'])

def main():
    # Main function to list files and folders recursively from the root folder.
    creds = get_credentials()
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    
    # Specify the source and destination folder IDs
    source_folder_id = 'source_ID'
    destination_folder_id = 'destination_ID'

    # Copy the folder
    copy_folder_recursive(service, source_folder_id, destination_folder_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is this error output related to some credentials issue or to the code itself?

```
An error occurred while copying file: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/"source_ID"/copy?alt=json returned "This file cannot be copied by the user.". Details: "[{'message': 'This file cannot be copied by the user.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'cannotCopyFile'}]">
```

Comment: Are the files you are trying to copy shortcuts?

Comment: The folder contains 4 Binary Files.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the mdn webdocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403), 403 means that the user is trying to perform an action in a resource they don't have permission to perform this action on. This particular excerpt is especially relevant here:

> This status is similar to 401, but for the 403 Forbidden status code, re-authenticating makes no difference

Based SOLELY on the information available here, it is likely that it is a matter of permissions(you wouldn't be able to copy the file even if you used the web interface) rather than credentials(You didn't authenticate correctly), as the latter should return a 401 error message and not a 403.

Comment: But if the authentication is down wrongly, this code shouldn't work with a different function neither, right? Or is for a copy process a different authentication needed?

Comment: Like I said, a 403 error means that you might be authenticated, but are not authorized to perform the action. 
*Authentication => This user exists and has informed the correct password
*Authorization => This user has access to this resource

These 2 are not the same thing

Comment: Would you say, even if I can list the content via Python with the same credentials for the source and destination folder, it would still be possible that there is an authorization issue for the copy process?

Comment: Yes, that is possible: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494893?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cprevent-people-from-downloading-printing-or-copying-your-file
You can individually allow people to read files but not copy them, for example.

Comment: @x0100 if I have answered your question, could you please accept my answer?

Comment: Not really. I mean, it is true that there are possibilities to limit the possibilities for other people. But in my case, I'm the owner of the files, everything is happening in my drive. I have a script with more or less the same structure to list the files, it works. I have another script to upload files, this also works. Just the copy function is throwing this error and till now I have no idea why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of found the problem with my initial code. My mistake was that folders in Google Drive can't be copied. Therefor the folder needs to be newly created and afterwards the files can be copied.

The script now works if I copy a folder within "My Drive" or if I copy a shared folder into "My Drive".

BUT if I want to copy a folder into a shared drive or if I try to copy a complete shared drive into another shared drive I get an error:

```
An error occurred while creating folder: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?alt=json returned "File not found: shared_drive_id.". Details: "[{'message': 'File not found: shared_drive_id.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'location': 'fileId', 'locationType': 'parameter'}]">
```

How can I make this script also work with shared drives?

```py
import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# Constants
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json'
CREDENTIALS_PATH = 'credentials.json'

def get_credentials():
    # Gets user credentials or prompts for authorization if needed.
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(TOKEN_PATH, SCOPES) if os.path.exists(TOKEN_PATH) else None

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CREDENTIALS_PATH, SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

        # Save the credentials for future runs
        with open(TOKEN_PATH, 'w') as token_file:
            token_file.write(creds.to_json())

    return creds

def get_file_metadata(drive_service, file_id):
    # Get file metadata by ID.
    return drive_service.files().get(fileId=file_id, fields='name').execute()

def copy_file(drive_service, source_file_id, destination_folder_id):
    # Copy a file to a destination folder.
    source_file_metadata = get_file_metadata(drive_service, source_file_id)
    source_file_name = source_file_metadata.get('name', 'Unknown File')

    file_metadata = {
        'name': source_file_name,
        'parents': [destination_folder_id],
    }

    try:
        copied_file = drive_service.files().copy(fileId=source_file_id, body=file_metadata).execute()
        print(f'File copied with ID: {copied_file["id"]}')
        return copied_file
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'An error occurred while copying file: {str(e)}')
        return None

def create_folder(drive_service, name, parent_folder_id):
    # Create a folder within a parent folder.
    file_metadata = {
        'name': name,
        'parents': [parent_folder_id],
        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
    }

    try:
        new_folder = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata).execute()
        print(f'Folder created with ID: {new_folder["id"]}')
        return new_folder
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'An error occurred while creating folder: {str(e)}')
        return None

def copy_folder_recursive(drive_service, source_folder_id, destination_folder_id):
    # Recursively copy a folder and its contents to a destination folder.
    results = drive_service.files().list(
        pageSize=1000,
        q=f"'{source_folder_id}' in parents",
        fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType)",
    ).execute()

    source_folder_metadata = get_file_metadata(drive_service, source_folder_id)
    source_folder_name = source_folder_metadata['name']

    new_folder = create_folder(drive_service, source_folder_name, destination_folder_id)

    if new_folder:
        for item in results.get('files', []):
            if item['mimeType'] == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder':
                copy_folder_recursive(drive_service, item['id'], new_folder['id'])
            else:
                copy_file(drive_service, item['id'], new_folder['id'])

def main():
    # Main function to copy a folder and its contents from the source to the destination.
    creds = get_credentials()
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Specify the source and destination folder IDs or shared drive IDs
    source_id = 'source_ID'
    destination_id = 'source_ID'

    # Copy the folder
    copy_folder_recursive(service, source_id, destination_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```